# Is is possible to find out what R packages are not being used in R shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a legacy shiny app passed on. I see the list of the packages mentioned and seems to be a long list. Is it possible to figure out which of the packages are not being used so that we don't have to load unnecessary packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could just add the session info to the app:

**server.R:**

```
 output$sessioninfo <- renderPrint(sessionInfo())
```

**ui.R:**

```
verbatimTextOutput("sessioninfo")
```